# iOS page transition with UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, animation, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I wanna animate page transitions in a UISplitView. The code I am using is...

```
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;



if (row == 0) {
    FirstDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
}

if (row == 1) {
    SecondDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
}

NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
[viewControllers release];

if (popoverController != nil) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

if (rootPopoverButtonItem != nil) {
    [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:self.rootPopoverButtonItem];
}

[detailViewController release];
```

How can I do that? Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Use a [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html) as the detail view controller of your split view. It supports page animations and transitions.